# Check if List of Object is already exist by comparing its attribute/property with a string

Tags: java, android, loops, equals

I need some help on how am I supposed to check if my list of my object is going to be duplicated by comparing each object fields or attribute to a given string value.

**My POJO**

```
public class AnnouncementModel extends AnnouncementsID {

  public String title, description, image, time;

  //Needed for Firebase
    public AnnouncementModel(){}

    public AnnouncementModel(String title, String description, String image, String time) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.time = time;

    }
}
```

What I want is to compare my given String id to the announcement's id like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < announcementList.size(); i++) {
    //Check if the deleted document ID is equal or exist in the list of announcement
    if(myGivenID.equals(announcementList.get(i).AnnouncementsID)) {

        //If yes then delete that object in list by targeting its index
        Log.d(TAG, "Removed city: " + announcementList.get(i).getTitle());
        announcementList.remove(i);
        //Notify the adapter that some item gets remove
        announcementRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
        announcementRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(i,announcementList.size()-1);
     }
}
```

But I do not want to loop it since all I want is to check if it is already exist and I don't need it index too. Is it possible? I saw that this can be done using Java 8 Stream API but in my case I can't use it since it is not compatible with Android SDK 23 and below. Can anyone give a full sample code for it?

Comment: Why not use a `Set` instead of list to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: Use a `Set` and make your POJO implement `equals()` as well as `hashCode()`. Doing so disables the `Set` to store duplicates, as far as I know...

Comment: could you give an example? I'm not familiar with Set but as I recall using that will need some sorting and I do not want to sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

For the `equals()` method to work as you expect, the class `AnnouncementModel` needs to implement the methods `hashcode()` and `equals()`.

Eclipse can generate them for you. Otherwise any basic implementation will work.

Comment: This also can be done in Android Studio but how am I gonna use it? Can you give some reference or sample for that?

Comment: Plenty of examples out there. Just return an int for hashcode() and compare the fields for equals(). For example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equals-hashcode-methods-java/

Comment: Gonna check it Thanks :>